# every time i try to update my ubuntu i get this error message

Tags: apt

```
Err:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.9.214.107 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Updates`. Go to other software, and remove the repository related to slack. It seems that they either do not support Ubuntu 22.04 yet, or the repository is non-existent.